# How can I automate a button click in a Webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to automate [this](https://www.panerabread.com/en-us/mypanera/registration-page.html) webpage inside of Android. So far I got my webview to successfully fill out the form, but the only problem is the final button click at the bottom of the page. Here is my code:

```
    // Fill out form
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show WebView
            findViewById(R.id.webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join_first_name').value='" + name + "';void(0); ");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join_last_name').value='" + lastName + "';void(0); ");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join_email').value='" + email + "';void(0);");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join_confirm_email').value='" + email + "';void(0);");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join_password').value='" + password + "';void(0); ");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join_confirm_password').value='" + password + "';void(0); ");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('phone_number_a').value='231';void(0); ");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('phone_number_b').value='123';void(0); ");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('phone_number_c').value='2310';void(0); ");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join_i_agree').click();void(0); ");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join_card_not_available').click();void(0); ");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('#join-now-primary')[1];void(0); ");

            myWebView.pageDown(true);
            // Make sure a toast is only shown once.
            while (toastCheck) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click the \"join\" button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                toastCheck = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

My Question is: How can I click the button at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Have you tried myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join-now-primary').click();");

Comment: @Unglückspilz Just tried it now. Removing void doesn't make a difference, and the reason I used a [1] in it was because it was the second element with that id on the page.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) says ID must be document-wide unique.

[HTML 5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) says the same thing but in other words. It says that ID must be unique in its *home subtree*, which is basically the document if we [read the definition of it](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#home-subtree).

Source: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

You should contact with website developer I guess. Also you can trigger it like this:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('join-now-primary').click();
```

Edit:

That website is using jQuery, so you can use jquery functions, please try again like this:

```
  String injection = "javascript:"

  injection += "$('#join_first_name').val('"+lastName+"');"
  injection += "$('#join_email').val('"+email+"');"
  injection += "$('#join_confirm_email').val('"+email+"');"
  injection += "$('#join_password').val('"+password+"');"
  injection += "$('#join_confirm_password').val('"+password+"');"
  injection += "$('#phone_number_a').val('2122');"
  injection += "$('#phone_number_b').val('122');"
  injection += "$('#phone_number_c').val('122');"
  injection += "$('#join_i_agree').trigger('click');"
  injection += "$('#join_card_not_available').trigger('click');"

  /* trigger form*/
  injection += "var formElement = $('#join_now_form');"
  injection += "formHandler = new FormHandler('#join_now_form', {disableDefaultSubmision: true});"
  injection += "formHandler.clearError();"
  injection += "formHandler.init();"
  injection += "formHandler.submitHandler = function(){ formElement.trigger('submitHandler', [formHandler]);}"
  injection += "AccountModals.init(formHandler, 'registration');"

  webView.loadUrl(injection)
```

Comment: Well yeah I know it's a bad practice, but I only need to fill out the form. I don't own that website. And I have tried using that code to no avail.

Comment: yeah that does nothing. And you forgot every semicolon at the end of the sentences..

Comment: I just gave you the clue, I did write it in note pad. If it didn't do nothing, it should throw an error in console. You can override onConsoleMessage(...) in WebChromeClient : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onConsoleMessage(java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)

Comment: It doesn't do anything and it doesn't throw an error. It's supposed to fill out the form.